# Display GroundOverlay only when building is entirely within cameraView

Tags: java, android, google-maps

As stated in the title, essentially I only want to display the GroundOverlay when the camera is in view of the **entire** building. How would I accomplish this within the onCameraMove() method? As of now the overlay appears even when **part** of the building is within the camera view.

```
@Override
    public void onCameraMove(){
        LatLngBounds bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
        private static final LatLng Building1 = new LatLng(54.69726685890506,-2.7379201682812226);

        if(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom > 17){
            if (bounds.contains(Building1)) {
                  displayOverlay(); 
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `Building1` should be a list of the boundary points of the building, and you should check in a loop that ALL of them are contained in`bounds`:

```
...
List<LatLng> buildingPoints = new ArrayList<>();
buildingPoints.add(new LatLng(...,...))
buildingPoints.add(new LatLng(...,...))
...

...
if(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom > 17){
    boolean allPointsVisible = true;
    for (LatLng currBuildingPoint: buildingPoints) {
        if (!bounds.contains(currBuildingPoint)) {
            allPointsVisible = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (allPointsVisible) {
        displayOverlay();
    }
 }
 ...
```

Comment: Awesome! How would you go about doing the same thing but let's say you have multiple buildings? So for instance, building1 and building2 and you would want specific overlay to appear for each one depending on which one comes into your camera view.

Comment: @dantheman Just repeat code fragment in a loop for all your buildings.